# How to multiply a four dimensional python numpy array by a vector indexed by second dimension

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a four-dimensional array T (shape=(361,30,100,257)) that I need to scale by a 30-element vector, P. I need the resulting vector to have the same shape as the original T array, and I need the scaling to be indexed by the second element of T. I have tried the obvious:

```
for i in range(len(PressFrac)):
  theta = T[:,i,:,:]*(PressFrac[i])
```

but the resulting theta loses the second dimension.

What I need is the first, third, and fourth dimensions multiplied by PressFrac[i] and the second dimension (which is an array called "lev") preserved.

I have tried using np.expand_dims and np.insert below the loop to add back in the second dimension but I get various broadcast errors. I have tried the following and combinations thereof:

```
theta = np.expand_dims(theta, axis = 1)
np.insert(theta,1,lev,axis=1)
theta = np.stack(theta, lev, axis =1)
theta = np.array(theta)[:,np.newaxis,:,:]
```

Any ideas would be great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just write

```
T*P[:, np.newaxis, np.newaxis]
```

to get back a version of `T` with the second dimension scaled by `P`. NumPy's broadcasting rules line up the dimensions of arrays on the right, so you need to add two singleton dimensions to the end of `P` with `np.newaxis` like above. Then, we're multiplying `T` with something that has shape `(30,1,1)`, which is allowed.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I knew there had to be an easier solution.

Comment: Good answer, and nicely succinct explanation of the broadcasting rules.

Answer (score 1):

@macroeconomist's answer is totally correct, and has a nice explanation of the broadcasting rules to boot. The only thing I have to add is that you can make the syntax ever-so-slightly more concise by using `None` instead of `np.newaxis`. I wanted to see the broadcasting in action, so I wrote a short demonstration script:

```
import numpy as np

T = np.arange(4*5*6*7).reshape(4,5,6,7)
w = np.random.randint(1, 10, size=5)

res = T*w[:, None, None]

print('res shape\n%s\n' % (res.shape,))

print('T[:, 2, :, 0]\n%s\n' % T[:, 2, :, 0])
print('T[:, 2, :, 0] * w[2]\n%s\n' % (T[:, 2, :, 0]*w[2]))
print('res[:, 2, :, 0]\n%s\n' % res[:, 2, :, 0])
```

Output:

```
res shape
(4, 5, 6, 7)

T[:, 2, :, 0]
[[ 84  91  98 105 112 119]
 [294 301 308 315 322 329]
 [504 511 518 525 532 539]
 [714 721 728 735 742 749]]

T[:, 2, :, 0] * w[2]
[[ 588  637  686  735  784  833]
 [2058 2107 2156 2205 2254 2303]
 [3528 3577 3626 3675 3724 3773]
 [4998 5047 5096 5145 5194 5243]]

res[:, 2, :, 0]
[[ 588  637  686  735  784  833]
 [2058 2107 2156 2205 2254 2303]
 [3528 3577 3626 3675 3724 3773]
 [4998 5047 5096 5145 5194 5243]]
```